# Is there a way to work on multiple projects in CLion?

Tags: clion

I'm looking for a way to work on multiple projects in parallel in CLion IDE.

For now I can only work on each project in a window at a time, but I'm looking for a solution similar to Eclipse IDE (see below) - being able to see my different projects' directories on a side bar and choosing the one I want, compiling it by itself, etc.

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: No: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/opening-multiple-projects.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes**: CLion doesn't allow you to open multiple projects *from the menu* because it uses the *CMake* system, which is script based.

However, *CMake* is quite capable of encompassing multiple projects, and CLion will correctly parse your CMake file and show all relevant directories in the project explorer.

#### Example

To do this, just like in Visual Studio, you need a parent "solution" and one or more child "projects".

Here is a simple CMake example in which "my_solution" references two child projects, "my_application" and "my_library". Here, my three folders are arranged:

- `xxx/my_solution/CMakeLists.txt`
- `xxx/my_application/CMakeLists.txt`
- `xxx/my_library/CMakeLists.txt`

And `xxx/my_solution/CMakeLists.txt` simply reads:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(my_solution)

add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../my_library" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_library_output")
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../my_application" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_application_output")
```

Note that it *is* also permitted to put `my_application` and `my_library` *within* the `my_solution` directory, as in Visual Studio.

Comment: I've done this before with CLion.  It's not as turnkey a solution as Eclipse or Visual Studio, but it gets the job done!

Comment: Thanks, this solution works fine.
I've added some screenshots in another response below, works 100%

Comment: trying to get this to output to one single directory doesn't seem to work.

Comment: see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1537

Answer (score 19):

No. CLion either:

- opens a new window with the other project you want to work on
- **closes** your current project and opens the new one in the current window

as you can see in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/opening-multiple-projects.html). I think this is wanted in their design; probably to maintain CLion fast and reactive...

Comment: you can do that on linux

Answer (score 7):

Adding some visual clues based on the answer from @c-z

This is how my project structure looking -
[image]

This is how my root level CMakeLists.txt is looking -
[image]

Finally, this is how my sub-directory level CMakeLists.txt is looking -
[image]

**NOTE:**
You may choose to remove the outer level main.cpp file (I've deleted it)
Also, you can remove the project level executable to remove it from the run configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, Jetbrains has not yet added this feature, because this workaround is there and they are not getting enough usecase to prioritize this feature request.
If you have a compelling use case, you can post it in that ticket.
(Sorry, couldn't post the link, but you could find it easily.)

Comment: see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1537